# Cannot open the simplest Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

i basically copied the Modal example from [ng-bootstrap Modal Documentaion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) and it seems like im unable to open it.

As soon as I click on the button to open the Modal, Chrome's console shouts:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

This is my Modal Component code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'add-transaction',
    templateUrl: './app/components/add-transaction/AddTransaction.html'
})
export class AddTransaction {
    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

    open(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        });
    }

    private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
        if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
            return 'by pressing ESC';
        } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
            return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
        } else {
            return  `with: ${reason}`;
        }
    }
}
```

The Modal HTML:

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
</template>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="open(content)">New Transaction</button>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

This Modal component is being used by another component withing a `<th>`:

```
<th><add-transaction></add-transaction></th>
```

### UPDATE:

It might be worth noting that while debugging it, I could see that the error pops when on the `open` method when `this.modalService.open(content)` is being invoked

Comment: Please should us your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Heads up! The NgbModal service needs a container element with the ngbModalContainer directive. The ngbModalContainer directive marks the place in the DOM where modals are opened. Be sure to add  somewhere under your application root element.

This was what i was missing, the code example does not contain that `ngbModalContainer` on the template.

Adding it solved my problem and now the Modal pops!

Hope it'll be helpful to somebody :)

Comment: So, where did you place the `ngbModalConatainer`? Where did you find this information? Could you elaborate more on this? Maybe provide a link?

Comment: I found a [**really good example**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/modal/demos/basic/plnkr.html) of how to use the Bootstrap Modal right on [**Bootstrap's site**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) (hidden in plain sight). Hope these links help.

Comment: @WebWanderer Hello, the quote is from the ng-bootstrap Modal documentation, linked at the beginning of the question, and yes, thats the same documentation you linked here, you can find that `Heads up!` part there :)

Comment: @Demodave, it's no longer used; see my answer.

Comment: cc @WebWanderer see above comment

Comment: @WebWanderer the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.0.0-alpha.21 (2017-03-15), `ngbModalContainer` is [no longer used](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha21-2017-03-15) to determine the position:

> BREAKING CHANGES
>
> model: The `ngbModalContainer` directive is no longer needed and was removed from this project. Just remove any references to the `<template ngbModalContainer></template>` from your projects.

Instead, a `container` option [was added](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/1373), which [defaults to `<body>`](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/core/blob/d5b413790f2da05d9764d4b5fd78be5fe8054c96/src/modal/modal-stack.ts#L32-L33):

```
const containerSelector = options.container || 'body';
const containerEl = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
```

When scoping the Twitter Bootstrap CSS to one's own component (such as `<my-app>`) rather than including it globally, then due to the missing styling it might seem that the modal opens below your application. In that case, explicitly set the container:

```
this.modalService.open(myContent, {container: 'my-app'})
```